# Setting symbol type and render units in a Python script (plugin) for geometry generator layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, geometry-generator

I have a Geometry Generator symbol for layer, created by a script (QGIS plugin).
This is line symbol (`make_line()`, inside some `translate`/`offset_curve` transformations), but when added it is displayed as polygon.
Because this layer's main purpose is to display/visualize (between-point) data I would also like to change symbol render setting from MapUnits to Millimeters.

This is probably really simple to do, but I don't really know how to read or use [documentation](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.html#a336228c3c35cf4b5ec0a4ebfe786387c) , and I can't find examples (so I hope answer here might be useful for others).
Code more-or-less looks like this:

```
vlayer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)))
rndr = vlayer.renderer()

ggString = 'translate(make_line(...))'
gg = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
gg.setGeometryExpression(ggString)
rndr.symbol().appendSymbolLayer(gg)
```

I'd like to add lines like this:

```
gg.setSymbolType(Line)
gg.setUnits(MapUnits)
```

They should have `Qgis::SymbolType` and `Qgis::RenderUnit` types, but... how to define it? Documentation says only it should be [Line](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#acfdb1ecc099664e9579fd00ffa554a0c)/[MapUnits](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#aaadb33fd28f3970985054959480e3d78)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Line` is a class attribute of `Qgis.SymbolType` and can be referenced like so:

```py
gg = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
gg.setSymbolType(Qgis.SymbolType.Line)

# check the assigned type
gg.symbolType()
# <SymbolType.Line: 1>
```

Or by accessing it through the enumerator (see [here for documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgis.html#qgis.core.Qgis.SymbolType))

```
gg.setSymbolType(Qgis.SymbolType(1))
```

Similarly for the `RenderUnit` - ([documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgis.html#qgis.core.Qgis.RenderUnit)):

```py
gg.setUnits(Qgis.RenderUnit.MapUnits)
# or 
# gg.setUnits(Qgis.RenderUnit(1))

# check the assigned units
gg.units()
# <RenderUnit.MapUnits: 1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it should be simple solution, I just couldn't find examples, and because my programming experience is limited I'm not familiar with converting "raw" documentation to practical solutions (a lot easier is to do something "similar" to example, even if it's more complicated). But this is exactly what I needed - thanks again.